# Login using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm making a login system and this is my script. I can't figure out whats wrong, it might be the query.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//connect to database
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$Dbhost = 'localhost' ;
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
mysql_connect ($Dbhost , $dbuser , $dbpass);

//query

$query = "SELECT Password
FROM UsPa
WHERE Username = '$username';";

if (mysql_query($query) == $password){
header('Location: page1.html');
}
else{
header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

It won't go to page1.html. I'm trying to figure it out; any suggestions, comments or concerns?

Comment: You arnt printing anything before you call header location are you?

Comment: Please elaborate as to what is happening. Does it give you an error? Does it go to a different page?

Comment: Its not checking the password with the query the if statement

Comment: Btw, you should accept (press the green checkmark) by the answer you found best answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

If I have read your post correctly, and understood the question, the reason the page never redirects to page1 is because the condition is never correct.

Since you have to extract information from the mysql query before you can use it (mysql_fetch_assoc/array/object), you are setting the condition to false.

If the posted password (Please secure input before you put online!) needs to match the output, you will need to parse the query call with one of the above conditions.

With that said, the function that would most likely be needed here, depending on your required end result, would be mysql_num_rows.

Just in case, I will post examples of both possible questions here.

If you need to check user name AND password matches, do this:

```
<?php
// Posted data -- please check and secure -- this is not secure, as it stands.
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//connect to database
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$Dbhost = 'localhost' ;
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
mysql_connect ($Dbhost , $dbuser , $dbpass);

//query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `Password` FROM `UsPa` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '{$password}' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
{
    header('Location: page1.html');
}
else
{
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

Or, if you actually just want to check the user name and then, for some reason, check the password, use this.

```
<?php
// Posted data -- please check and secure -- this is not secure, as it stands.
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//connect to database
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$Dbhost = 'localhost' ;
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
mysql_connect ($Dbhost , $dbuser , $dbpass);

//query
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT `Password` FROM `UsPa` WHERE `Username` = '$username';");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($result['Password'] == $password)
{
    header('Location: page1.html');
}
else
{
    header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

With that in mind, I'd suggest the top action, since it makes no sense to do anything but check the DB and validate on the output of results.

EDIT:
Although you state you are new to programming, which may be the best chance to tell you this since you can then learn this instead of mysql_ - you should look into mysqli_

The I stands for Improved, which is the updated version of the mysql engine.

The reason for using mysqli_ over mysql_ is that mysql_ is now deprecated and in later versions of php it may be unable to be used -- what version is anybodies guess, but it will happen one day.

There are not a lot of difference between the 2, in the syntax, but it may be worth looking into a database class and using it as at a later date, this will make it a lot easier to switch databases (mysql_ to mysqli_ for example) and not leave you having to edit every file of your codes.

Being new to programming, this may not mean a lot to you right now, but is definitely worth researching to save yourself time later on, but as you are learning, makes sense to just learn this instead of having to go through your code to change another day.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_query($query) == $password){
```

This lines does not work. mysql_query() does not return a type comparable to `$password`.

You will need to do:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_password = $data['Password'];

if ($user_password == $password) {
...
```

With that in mind, you should not be using mysql, even if you're just learning. It is deprecated. At the minimum, learn using mysqli.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
You are comparing the mysql_query result resource to the user's password string, try adding a fetch_assoc() like this:

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//connect to database
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$Dbhost = 'localhost' ;
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
mysql_connect ($Dbhost , $dbuser , $dbpass);

//query
$query = "SELECT Password
FROM UsPa
WHERE Username = '$username';";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['Password'] === $password){
    header('Location: page1.html');
}else{
    header('Location: login.html');
}
```

I would use mysqli instead of mysql php functions which are deprecated.  I also recommend using prepared statements and you won't need the stripslashes and escaping to sanitize your input.  Try using these resources.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Your code with mysqli and prepared statements would look something like this(untested)

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$Dbhost = 'localhost' ;
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$query = "SELECT Password
FROM UsPa
WHERE Username = '?";

$db = new mysqli($Dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

$stmt->prepare($query))

$stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($dbPw);
$stmt->fetch();

if ( $dbPw === $password ) {
    header('Location: page1.html');
} else{
    header('Location: login.html');
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: this doesnt help much

Comment: The issue is mysql query returns a resource, not a string so you can't compare $password and get a match, I didn't post the solution using mysql_query because I thought switching to mysqli is the better solution.

Comment: What if he's writing a script for a server that does not run a recent enough version of PHP to support mysqli? I doubt it... but always answer the question first, and then make suggestions like not using deprecated functions.